# Convert to date to time zone in legacy BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

In new BigQuery SQL (standard) you can use `DATE(some_time_stamp, "Asia/Jerusalem")` in order to convert UTC to local time zone. I couldn't find such a function in legacy SQL for BigQuery.

How do I convert UTC timestamp to time zone time using legacy SQL in BigQuery?

Comment: just wondering: any reason that stops you from migration to standard?

Comment: @FelipeHoffa I want to create a view to be used by Google Data Studio - but data studio can not read views written in standard (weird!).

Comment: what if you create a custom query in Data Studio? #standardSQL SELECT * FROM `view`

Comment: @FelipeHoffa I'll tell our data guy to try that.

Answer (score 2):

There is no timezone function within legacy, only standard.  You would have to implement your own time conversion logic e.g.

```
SELECT   DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), 300, "MINUTE") PlusFiveHours
```